# SpringBoot app deployed on server doesn't want to connect with DB

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jar, executable-jar

I have a `Spring Boot` application with connection to `MySQL` locally. I have generated `jar` file to upload it on my `RaspberryPi` server. The `jar` file has generated successfuly but when I tried to run the application after deploying it on my server it throughs:

I see what is written below but I'm wondering how to deal with that problem because when I run it from `Intellij` locally it starts properly?

For your question, yes I have installed `MySQL` at the server.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar!/:5.1.40]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar!/:5.1.40]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar!/:5.1.40]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar!/:5.1.40]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1710) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar!/:5.1.40]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar!/:5.1.40]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar!/:5.1.40]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2104) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar!/:5.1.40]
        ... 58 common frames omitted

2017-05-08 17:45:21.543  WARN 29145 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

UPDATE: - added `application.properties`

```
# LOCAL DATABASE
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test3?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = admin

# REMOTE DATABASE
#spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:9090/test3
//in fact the address to the remote db is modraszka.sth.sth:8080
#spring.datasource.username = root
#spring.datasource.password = password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your credentials are fine and mysql is running as a service.You can check it in services.msc.

Comment: I have updated the post with `application.properties`